# How to check if key and value in a Map match

Tags: java, data-structures

I am tasked with asking a user for the capital of a state, and checking a maps value and key are a match.. I am unsure after looking through the functions for a map on how to do this. So I am trying to get the string value from the user, check the map to see if the value and key are a match, and if they are, tell the user.

I am trying to embedd the code, why is the embedd not working properly? I used the brackets for code input

```
enter code here while(!input.equals("q")){       //ask user for input (the key being the state) and outputting the value at that key(capital)
       System.out.println("What is the capital of "+states[k]);
       input = scanner.nextLine();
       if(map.get(input).equals(capitals[k]))
           System.out.println(input + " is the correct capital city of "+states[k]);
       else
           System.out.println(input + "is NOT the correct capital city of "+states[k]);
       k++;
   }
```

Comment: What you are asking is not clear to me. Please clarify and post it with [mcve]. If you have a `<String,String>`  (state, capital) map, there is no need for `capital` and `states` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you asking for. But what I understand is you want to do a basic key value lookup from HashMap which you populated.

```
if(map.get(input) != null && map.get(input).equals(state[k])){
   System.out.println("The capital of "+ input + " is "+map.get(input));
}
```

Comment: doesn't make sense why my edited post is getting an exception thrown. this is why I hate programming

Comment: There can be multiple reason for null pointer. You might not have that value in hashmap. So you need to check for null as in map.get(input) != null and check equals.